# Preserve order of closing services while shuting down the linux

Tags: linux, shutdown, reboot, systemd

I defined a Linux systemd service which has few dependencies in unit file using "After=" and "Requires=". My service depends also on SAN filesystems controlled by Veritas.

When stopping my service upon shutdown I noticed my service is stopped after VCS service which fails my service to stop gracefully (as it requires filesystems controlled by Veritas to stop which are not present).

I have following dependencies set:

```
After=vcs.service vxfs.service vxvm-boot.service

Requires=vcs.service vxfs.service vxvm-boot.service
```

Any idea how can I set the right order during shutdown to call my service before Veritas services and which Veritas services I should depend on?

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/752649/108618).

Comment: The U&L copy has been closed in favor of this one. If the OP and/or the community would prefer the Q to be at U&L, simply ping me on either post.